# Parent-Child without FK inserting in wrong order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a legacy SQL Server database I'm in no position to significantly change for many reasons.  There is a parent/child relationship between two tables.  There are no foreign keys between these two tables.  There is also a `FOR INSERT` trigger in the child table that checks for the existence of a parent record.  If there is no parent record then the insert fails due to the trigger using `raiserror`.

I'm trying to add some records to the parent/child tables.  I add a new record to the parent table first.  Then I add multiple records to the child tables next.  I've verified the order is correct via logging statements.  When the `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` method is called a `DbUpdateException` is thrown with the same error message the trigger has in `raiserror`.

The problem is the child records are being added first, even though I am adding the parent record first in code.  **Is there any way to fix this without changing the database?**  I realize the current database design here is not ideal, but it's outside of my control.

I can call `SaveChangesAsync` after the parent is inserted, but then I give up the transaction benefits of only calling `SaveChangesAsync` once at the end of the operation.  Is there any other solution to influence the ordering of Entity Framework database inserts?

Comment: I think EF will always insert child entities first, unless modeled otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no possibility to set the order of **independent** entities insertion (i.e. without foreign keys). It's EF's internal mechanism.
There is no problem in EF to call `SaveChanges` multiple times during one transaction. Look on `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` or "old-fashioned" `TransactionScope`.

[Similar discussion on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67ee0597-e16d-4d84-8b22-e28b2364c5ae/getting-correct-order-of-execution-of-insert-update-and-delete-operations-before-savechanges?forum=adodotnetentityframework).